# How to handle the situation when user closes the geolocation popup

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I using `HTML5` geolocation to track user's location in my application.

I'm able to handle almost every situation like when he denies the permission, when he allows the permission, timeout and even some errors occurs also. But when user closes the popup box, then how can I know programatically that user closes the popup? I want to handle this situation/case. Similarly in Firefox, when he clicks on 'Not now' option. I want to handle this two cases.

Answer (score 0):

when user closes the popup box ,you can raise a custom function in your popup box ! 
The premise is that the popup box is written by youself.

The second case's solution is that you can prepare a click event for 'Not now' option.

Comment: but popup is raising by browser by default,then how can I write my own popup

Comment: If that's the case, I can't help you!